# Prevent bots submitting to external server

Tags: javascript, security, recaptcha

I'm trying to block bots client side.

The form submits to the payment provider and the payment provider posts back the request response to our server.

I added a recaptcha to the page which enables the button to submit the form once completed. Clearly, this isn't helping at all as simply calling `document.forms[0].submit();` gets around this.

Given that I can only work client side, am I correct in saying there's no way to prevent a targeted attack?

Any javascript tricks are visible to the inspector. I'm guessing I need to switch to a payment provider and let it be their problem?

I was also thinking to disable paste in the cc fields but FF can override that, besides, given that the form submission details are easy to see, chances are are that the bot is just creating a post string and submitting it to the payment provider.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to handle this.

First, assuming the payment provider still passes through the original form information, you can still implement a more-or-less typical CAPTCHA challenge. A bot with an invalid CAPTCHA response can still make it through to the payment provider, but you can then detect and reject the response once it makes it through to you.

Second, consider a "proof of work" mechanic. Have some JavaScript that performs a busywork calculation that will take some time to complete. For human visitors, this work will just be done in the background while they're completing your form, but for a bot going for high-speed, high-volume interactions, it's a real problem. This doesn't do anything to *block* the bot, but it's sometimes an effective deterrent.

But most effectively, why does your form need to submit directly to the payment provider? Couldn't you submit to your own server-side code to process the CAPTCHA and then submit or redirect from there to the payment provider? (I've used this architecture with weird payment systems in the past, and none of them have had any trouble with it.)

Comment: 1. Could the bot writer not just inspect the post request and add the new token?
2. Same again, check the mechanic and adjust script accordingly?
3. Same payment provider has a server to server option, we'll most likely switch to that.
Many thanks!

Comment: It all depends on the visibility of the script. If you have human attackers writing bots to specifically target your application, then of course nothing you do on the client side can really stop them precisely because they can reverse engineer whatever you do. But if you're just the target of an automated bot attack, the bots aren't that smart.

Comment: pretty sure they are targetting us. We're moving to a server to server payment provider, it's the only way really